# "The field <> must be a number", but my field is optional

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm using ASP.NET MVC4 for a new app.  I'm pretty new to it and am struggling with something that should be easy, but can't get it to work.

I have a `int?` field on my database.  My EF code first model has this:

```
public int? Effort { get; set; }
```

The above line is also in my viewmodel.  This is in the view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Effort)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Effort, new { @class="wide100" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Effort)    
</div>
```

When I try to save the record without any input in for Effort, I get this error:

> The field Effort must be a number.

Why is that?  My field is optional.

Same error shows if I use alpha characters, but that is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try `TextBoxFor`

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Effort)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Effort, new { @class="wide100" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Effort)    
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check your client side validations? may be something is wrong there. because, your code seems correct.